# React - child.ref.current is null in componentdidmount

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ref

Here's many similar questions but I still couldn't solve this problem.

`Child's ref` is null in Listner.

I really don't understand what this is.

The code is below.

- react 17.0.1

```
// Parent.tsx
const Parent: React.FC<{id: string}> = (props) => {
  const [id] = useState(props.id)  
  const modalRef = createRef<ModalRef>();

  // If I registerd the Listner here, modalRef is not null but,
  // multiple Listner has registered.

  useEffect(() => {
    listner.on('MODAL_POPUP', (o:{param:string}) => {
      modalRef.current?.pop(o.param); // <--- modalRef.current is null
    });
    return() => {};
  }, []);

  return (
    <Modal ref={modalRef} id={id}>
      <div>contents</div>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

```
// Modal.tsx
export interface ModalProps {
  id: string;
}
export interface ModalRef {
  pop: () => void;
}

const Modal = React.forwardRef<ModalRef, ModalProps>((props, ref) => {
  const [id] = useState(props.id);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    pop() {
      console.log('popup modal');
    },
  }));

  return createPotal(
    <div>contents..</div>,
    document.getElementById('modal-root') as HTMLElement,
  );
});
```

Any advice for me?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you forwarding the ref in your Modal component?

Comment: @SamiElk yes. `Modal` has forwardRef.

Comment: Does your portal work? Isn't it : `createPortal(<Component />, portalTargetElement)`

Comment: @SamiElk yes yes. that code is summary. that is not the point of question. 
`document.getElementById('modal-root') as HTMLElement` is below.

Comment: @SamiElk Fantastic!! It works. Thank you soooo much. I wasted 2 days because of this.

Comment: You're welcome, I deleted my comment because I still had errors when testing since I don't have your whole code base. But glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `useRef` for creating the `ref` in React Function Components, so change it to this:

```
const Parent: React.FC<{id: string}> = (props) => {
  const [id] = useState(props.id)  
  const modalRef = useRef<ModalRef>(); // <== here

  useEffect(() => {
    listner.on('MODAL_POPUP', (o:{param:string}) => {
      modalRef.current?.pop(o.param); 
    });
    return() => {
      listner.off('MODAL_POPUP', ()=>{});
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Modal ref={modalRef} id={id}>
      <div>contents</div>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks you for the reply. 
If I use `useRef`, `ref={modalRef}` has error.

Comment: Type 'MutableRefObject<ModalRef | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Ref<ModalRef> | undefined'. Blah Blah..

Comment: @IanCho add your `Modal` component so I could see its code

Comment: Also add the definition of the ModalRef type

Comment: Updated the question. added `Modal.tsx`

Comment: @TaghiKhavari Thank you for the reply! I solved it. I use this code `const modalRef = useRef<ModalRef>(null); `

Comment: @IanCho Cheers!, if the answer was helpful try to give an upVote to it ;)